# Почему не работает пользовательское исключение Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

IndexController.php:

```
public function testException(){
        try{
            echo $test;
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
                throw new PostsInCategoryNotFoundErrorException($e);
        }

    }
```

PostsInCategoryNotFoundErrorException.php

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class PostsInCategoryNotFoundErrorException extends Exception
{

}
```

Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof PostsInCategoryNotFoundErrorException) {
      echo 'Ошибка в переменной';
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Все равно выдает свою стандартную страницу ошибки "Whoops, looks like something went wrong"

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `echo 'Ошибка в переменной';` сделать `return 'Ошибка в переменной';`

Comment: Не работает никак, все варианты вывода уже перепробовал